# How we find the database instance name from procedure in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is: if I write a store procedure like this:

```
create procedure test
as
begin
    select * from databasename..Tablename 
end

create procedure test1
as
begin
    select * from databasename..Tablename 
end
```

Then how to find the `databasename..` from above both procedure? I need a query to find the list of procedure name who used like `Databasename..tablename`. inside the procedure stuff

Comment: Please format the code in your question and add more details.

Comment: Use ANTLR to parse your query and then you will find the database name easily.

Comment: What is a _"database instance name"_? And what in the world is _"the list of procedure name who used like Databasename..tablename. inside the procedure stuff"_?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create procedure test
as
begin
    select * from databasename..Tablename 
end

GO

create procedure test1
as
begin
    select * from databasename..Tablename 
end

GO




DECLARE @SearchWord NVARCHAR(128) = 'databasename..Tablename'

SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%'+@SearchWord+'%' 
UNION
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) 
FROM SYSCOMMENTS 
WHERE [text] LIKE '%'+@SearchWord+'%' 
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
UNION 
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%'+@SearchWord+'%'
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it will work for every key word you want and object - functions, views, procedures, triggers.

Comment: Thanks so much. Its very help full for us.

Comment: If this answered your question, then please mark it as the answer.